# Issue with some games - extremely low framerate in menus (~1 fps)

Tags: windows-7, performance, fps

(I know Superuser isn't for games, but I suspect this issue technically stems from a non-gaming problem. Since it's likely computer hardware or software related, I figured it's relevant.)

Hey guys, I have an M17x-R1 with the following hardware:

- Single GTX 260m with 280.19 beta drivers
- 4gb ram
- Q9000 OC'ed to 2.4ghz
- Win 7 64bit

For whatever reason, certain games that I have are experiencing extremely poor performance. The 3 games I've noticed this on are the Battlefield 3 alpha trial, Just Cause 2, and Brink. I can't even start playing the game because I'm getting 1 frame per second in menus and intro videos.

I'm able to play most other games (Battlefield: Bad Company 2, ESIV: Oblivion, TF2, Monday Night Combat, EVE Online, Dead Space, Left 4 Dead, etc.) all at max settings with good framerate.

Any ideas on what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have heard it before, but, try different drivers!

Comment: All my drivers are up to date. 280.19 was released just 2 weeks ago and it was made specifically to help with the Battlefield 3 alpha. EDIT: I'll try reverting to older drivers.

Comment: Switching to 275.33, the latest stable release, didn't fix anything unfortunately.

Comment: I had to revert all the way back to 257.38, but it finally did work. I guess I should have tried this first.